# ¿Cómo dar un valor diferente a una variable por cada iteración?

Tags: php

```
$azul = "#4285f4"; // Azul
$verde = "#34a853"; // Verde
$amarillo = "#fbbc05"; // Amarillo
$rojo = "#ea4335"; // Rojo
$color = rand(1, 4);
```

Estoy usando `$color` dentro de un ***loop*** pero de esta forma tan simple que es mi código, el valor de la variable se repite, tipo: `3, 3, 1`.

¿Cómo hacer que en `3 iteraciones` el valor no se repita? formando secuencias del tipo `1, 2, 3`, `1, 3, 2`, `3, 2, 1`, `3, 1, 2`, etc...

```
while ( $destacados->have_posts() ) {

     if($color == 1) { $color = $azul; }
     elseif ($color == 2) { $color = $verde; }
     elseif ($color == 3) { $color = $amarillo; }
     elseif ($color == 4) { $color = $rojo; }
}
```

---

**Pregunta original *(portugués)* :** [Como atribuir um valor diferente a variável em cada loop? - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102405/como-atribuir-um-valor-diferente-a-vari%C3%A1vel-em-cada-loop)

Comment: Si entiendo bien, quieres que en la primera iteración estén disponibles cuatro colores, en la segunda iteración tres (eliminando el previamente seleccionado), en la tercera iteración dos (eliminando los dos previos) y en la cuarta poner el color faltante... y después reiniciar. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: @Barranka es correcto, el objetivo es que en el resultado de los colores, no se repita alguno.

Comment: ¿Tu arreglo final puede ser de cualquier longitud `N`? Asumiendo *k* colores, si fuera de tamaño *k*, bastaría con una permutación de colores; si fuera menor, debería ser un subconjunto de la permutación. Pero si fuera mayor, inevitablemente habrá repeticiones... así que necesitarías `N / k` permutaciones (redondeado al entero inmediato superior), y "truncando" la última para llenar el arreglo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Asumiendo que existe un array llamado `$colores` de tamaño `k`, y quieres llenar un array `$colores_aleat`  de tamaño `N`, se me ocurren dos posibles casos:

1. Si `N <= k`, entonces basta con hacer una permutación de `$colores` y tomar los primeros `N` elementos de esta permutación.
2. Si `N > k`, entonces hay que generar `p = N / k` permutaciones (redondeadas al entero superior), y "unir" las `p` permutaciones, y tomar las primeras `N` entradas

Veamos si esto funciona:

```
$colores = array("rojo", "verde", "azul", "amarillo");
$k = count($colores);
$N = 10;  // Valor de ejemplo; el array $colores_aleat tendrá $N entradas
if($N <= $k) {
    /*
      Si el número de colores a obtener es menor o igual que el número de colores disponibles
      basta con obtener los primeros $N elementos de una permutación de $colores
     */
    $colores_aleat = array_slice(shuffle($colores), 0, $N);
} else {
    /*
      Si el número de colores a obtener es mayor que el número de colores disponibles
      entonces hay que llenar el arreglo con permutaciones sucesivas
     */
    $colores_aleat = array();
    $p = ceil($N / $k);
    for($i = 1; $i <= $p; $i++) {
        $colores_aleat = array_merge($colores_aleat, shuffle($colores));
    }
    $colores_aleat = array_slice($colores_aleat, 0, $N);
}
```

Quizá no es lo más eficiente, pero funciona.

Espero sea útil.

Answer (score 11):

Defines un arreglo de colores en lugar de las variables de manera independiente, y usas el método shuffle para variar la posición de los mismos, luego con `array_shift()` vas removiendo lo que ya no usas, de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$colores = ["#4285f4", "#34a853", "#fbbc05","#ea4335"];
shuffle($colores);

$i = 0;
$tot = count($colores);

while($i < $tot){
  echo array_shift($colores);
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: _debes_ indicar que el post es una traduccion si pertenece a otro sitio de stack exchange.

Comment: ahora que lo dices, da la casualidad, que el código de la mejor respuesta del enlace es casi idéntico al mío jeje, pero no fue esa mi intención, realmente no estoy a favor de las traducciones.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla una pequeña corrección. Quitaría ese 4 _hardcodeado_ y pondría un `count($colores)` y optaría por un `for` en vez de un `while`.

Comment: bien, pero no es un corrección ya que las correcciones se aplican solo a errores, sería una optimización, lo del count está bueno, lo otro (while-for) para este pequeño ejemplo no le veo gran cambio, igual no perdamos el foco, que es responder a la pregunta.